# Can resharper navigate to a method?

Tags: resharper

I know how to navigate to a file or a class, but can I navigate to a class's method?

Oh and say I am viewing a different class's file

Comment: See ReSharper's navigation and search [features description](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html) and [keyboard shortcut reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#navigation_and_search).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use "Resharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA" keyboard scheme:

> Ctrl + Shift + Alt + N -> navigate to symbol

In Visual Studio Scheme:

> Shift + Alt + T

For future reference and other options check  https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html

Comment: That's right, hard to get used to press so many keys, but don't forget you can re-assign shortcuts for resharper functions too.

Comment: If you allowed ReSharper to override the default VS shortcuts this does not work, see the answer from Jim G. instead.

Comment: Does it work to fin a method in the same file ? For javascript ? I can't make it work

Comment: For Javascript it works too but in my experience not 100% of the times. If you have the file open and in focus you can try CTRL+F12 too, it will list the symbols in the current file.

Answer (score 54):

With respect to my correctly configured keybindings, all of the previous answers seem outdated/invalid to me.

I say:

- Hit `Alt + \` to list all file members.
- Then find your method in the list and navigate to it.

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work for the currently opened file. Is there any way to make it work globally for the entire solution?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Resharper IDEA Scheme, do ctrl + F12 and you can enter a member name, fastest way to navigate to a method, property etc on that file

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl + Click (or Right Click > Go To Declaration). Works on Methods, Fields, Properties, Types, and just about everything else.

Comment: You can also just click on the method  name and press `F12`.

Answer (score 2):

With VS2015 and ReSharper 10 press **Ctrl** + **T**. This will search for *types*, *symbols* and *files*. It will search through everything in your solution.

Update: works the same in VS2017 and ReSharper 2017.2.
You can also press **Ctrl + T** followed by **/ mm** to search for just methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip for the current file is to use the File Structure window - can also drag and drop members around from the window.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Dpack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) ([f/oss](http://dpack.codeplex.com/)) for years and it can go to methods and/or properties by pressing a shortcut and then start typing.  For those who get Resharper's ctrl-T working it is like that one but within the file.

Dpack provides the same functionality for finding files and open files. The former is a better version of Visual Studio 2015's ctrl-;.

(I have done some remapping of keys too but in my experience something (resharper?) overwrites my changes from time to time.)
(Also with VS2015 and R#9.2 I think Dpack does a better job at this.)